# iOS crash @ NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following code crashes continuously on iOS. Please help me to find out the exact cause for this **error**.

```
  @try {                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[attrString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding) } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //Any UI updates
                    [self.attributedLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
                });
            });
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DLog(@"Trace exception : %@",exception.description);
    }
    @finally {
    }
```

And got the following message from Xcode organiser:

[image]

Comment: Rather than using try/catch in objective c, you should supply an NSError reference to the `error` parameter and see if error is non-nil.

Comment: Also how does try/catch work with GCD?

Answer (score 7):

Using the HTML importer (`NSHTMLTextDocumentType`) is only possible on the main thread.

> NSAttributedString has used WebKit for all import (but not for export)
>   of HTML documents. Because WebKit document loading is not thread safe,
>   this has not been safe to use on background threads
>
> The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that
>   is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute
>   with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType).

(Source:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/CreatingAttributedStrings.html)

So try running the code in main queue instead global queue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely helped me figure out a weird crash that involved WebKit and attributed strings in a total unrelated usage.